# Passing script after validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to validate all the textboxes to make sure they are all filled before allowing a user to proceed. I've got 2 buttons involved. The first button is sent to javascipt, to validate, and the second to vb.net to upload files and save the details into database. Each button is working perfectly if I manually click them. the problem is, I cant get them to work together. (IE. Press the first button to initiate javascript check, if successful, call button 2 to initiate vb.net script to add to database and redirect. )

this is the validation script (in javascript)

```
function fnCheck() {

        if ((document.getElementById("price").value).length > 0) {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure the details are correct?");
            if (r == true) {
                document.getElementById("Submit1");
            }
            else {
                x = "You pressed Cancel!";
            } 

        }


    }
```

and this a sample of my vb.net textbox + code (not using codebehind)

```
<script runat="server">

    Sub SubmitButton_Click(Source As Object, e As EventArgs)

        Response.Redirect("../services.html")
    End Sub

</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="price" runat="server" CausesValidation="true"></asp:TextBox>

<input id="Submit1" runat="Server" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click" 
                            type="submit" value="Upload Files" />
<asp:Button ID="Button5" runat="server" Text="1" 
                                OnClientClick="javascript:return fnCheck()"/>
```

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: The `fnCheck()` is meant to return nothing?

Comment: The fnCheck() is suppose to call the Submit1 button "document.getElementById("Submit1");" when the user clicks ok to continue with the file upload and adding to database. which I'm still figuring out how to do as the document.getElementById("Submit1"); doesn't take me there

Comment: I'm not too familiar with vb.net langage but from scripting point of view the `document.getElementById("Submit1")` will only return the DOM element not submit the form.

Answer (score 1):

ALthough I'm not familiar with vb.net spirit, but if you are trying to simulate a click event on the `<input>` element, try the following:

Change input type to button:

```
<input id="Submit1" runat="Server" onserverclick="SubmitButton_Click" 
                        type="button" value="Upload Files" />
```

Invoque the `click()` method on the button element:

```
function fnCheck() {

    if ((document.getElementById("price").value).length > 0) {
        var r = confirm("Are you sure the details are correct?");
        if (r == true) {
            document.getElementById('Submit1').click();
        }
        else {
            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
        } 

    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've changed the input to button with the id "Submit1", changed the code to sub submit1_click(sender as object, e as system.eventargs) handles submit1.click, and changed javascript to document.getelementbyid('submit1').click(); my buttons still work when I press them manually, but it doesn't work if it goes through fnCheck().. any other ideas? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that the `fnCheck()` method is invoked? Add some trace code to check if the application goes in the `fnCheck()` function.

Comment: It's working, because the confirm popup is working. if I change the document.getelement to a redirect it works as well... might be missing something in the "document.getElementById instead..

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to do a postback, just call __doPostback:

```
function fnCheck() {

        if ((document.getElementById("price").value).length > 0) {
            var r = confirm("Are you sure the details are correct?");
            if (r == true) {
                __doPostBack("Submit1", "");
            }
            else {
                x = "You pressed Cancel!";
            } 

        }


}
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried that before, but somehow, it just refreshes the page. nothing else happens. not even the redirect..

Answer (score 0):

Quite old question but still for any one else..

Check whether the page is inheriting a master page, if yes, the id "Submit1" of button will get changed on the client side to something as "**contentplaceholder__Submit1**".

if you want to prevent that from happening add this to your submit button Code:

```
ClientIDMode="Static"
```